# Ajax GET request fails in laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, get-request

when i try to send a GET request with tutorial ,but its not working and end up with 500 internal server error
I cant find any error by searching on forum or stackoverflow,and also i ma beginner, kindly seek your help

here is my view ajax.blade.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Ajax Example</title>

      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>

      <script>
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "getmsg",
         success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
         },
         error: function(data){
             console.log("fail");
         }
        });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

here is the controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class aController extends Controller
{
    function index() {
      return response()->json(array('d'=> 'success'));
    }
}
```

here is web.php
`Route::get('getmsg',[aController::class,'index']);`

Comment: Welcome to SO ... check the error logs and see why you are getting a 500 error

Comment: Note that you pasted the same code twice.

Comment: Change `APP_DEBUG=true` from your .env file. and come back here with the error message

Comment: maybe can try add this line `use App\Http\Controllers\aController;` above your `Route::get('getmsg',[aController::class,'index']);`  laravel 8 change the default namespace in route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your route with

```
use App\Http\Controllers\aController;

Route::get('/getmsg', [aController::class, 'index']);
```

Laravel 8 requires you to provide a complete path to the controller or you can define a default namespace to locate your controllers like this, define following in your `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

You should get a response from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if you are using `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`, slim version are not supported so remove slim version and replace it with:

```js
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

then after if library link is correct check for things like csrf, route, data etc.